# count the number of affected rows and display the number in a messagebox

Tags: vb.net, numbers, rows

how do i count the number of rows that are affected when I updated a table, and display the number of affected rows in a message box ??

here is my code for updating the table ...

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    req = row.Cells(Column1.Name).Value
    If row.Cells("Column1").Value = True Then
        Dim sql2 As String = "UPDATE EquipmentDetail SET Requested = '" & req & "' WHERE SerialNumber = '" & serials & "'"
        cmd2.Connection = connection
        cmd2.CommandText = sql2
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
Next
connection.Close()
```

End Sub

help would be appreciated ... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executeNonQuery method returns the number of affected rows. Just use that number and show in a message box.

Comment: For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    req = row.Cells(Column1.Name).Value
    If row.Cells("Column1").Value = True Then
        Dim sql2 As String = "UPDATE EquipmentDetail SET Requested = '" & req & "' WHERE SerialNumber = '" & serials & "'"
        cmd2.Connection = connection
        cmd2.CommandText = sql2
        x = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
Next
MessageBox.Show(x)

is this the right way to do it ?? It always returns a value of 1 even though I updated 3 rows ...

Comment: @user989811, yes it's the right way. And you're sure that you are updating 3 rows?

Comment: hmm yes ... I selected three checkboxes ... i also looked at the EquipmentDetail table and three cells were updated into true from false ...

Comment: Hmmm, your doing a foreach, do you get a messge box with 1 three times?

Comment: yes I did when i put the messagebox inside the foreach ... but only once when I put it outside the foreach ...

Comment: Ok, if I understand this correct the sql command only updates one row at the time, but you want to know the total. If you just sum the rows affected you will get 3 wich was the result you expected. So introduce a variable and add to that for the total count.

Comment: hmmm .. im very new to executenonquery and don't know how to manipulate the results ...

Comment: You don't have to manipulate the result. Just create a variable called sum outside the loop and then set sum = sum + cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()  then after the loop MessageBox.Show(sum)